# Payment System for Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms, payment

Im looking for a payment system that i can use for an Orchard site.
The site is for a hotel and you should be able to pay for a room.
is there a module for that?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is an existing module that will fulfil that specific requirement, but there are a couple of great ecommerce modules that you can extend fairly easily:

- [Nwazet Commerce](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Nwazet.Commerce)
- [Magelia Webstore](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.WebStore)

There is also a [great tutorial by Sipke Schoorstra](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1) that will put you well on your way to writing your own.

Comment: all links don't work !